# decrypting function is lauching error at the end

Tags: python

I want to create a decrypt script in python, my function filename = allfiles(); return the path where is the files , but I try to decrypt my files launch me the error like this below. How can I fix it? I am using python 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File "F:\bug_bounty\decrypt.py", line 41, in <module>
     if os.path.basename(filename).startswith("(encrypted)"):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 208, in basename
     return split(p)[1]
   File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 180, in split
     d, p = splitdrive(p)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 116, in splitdrive
     normp = p.replace(altsep, sep)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os
import random
import sys


def decrypt(key, filename):
    outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename),
                           os.path.basename(filename[11:]))
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        filesize = infile.read(16)
        IV = infile.read(16)

        decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

        with open(outFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break

                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))

            outfile.truncate(int(filesize))


def allfiles():
    allFiles = []
    for (root, subfiles, files) in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for names in files:
            allFiles.append(os.path.join(root, names))

    return allFiles


password = 'M4st3rRul3zs'
filename = allfiles();
for files in filename:
    if os.path.basename(filename).startswith("(encrypted)"):
       print "%s is already encrypted" %filename
       pass
    else:  
        decrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), filename)
        print "Done decrypting %s" %filename
        """os.remove(filename)"""
```

Comment: I would say you have your variable names backwards, i.e. `files = allfiles(); for filename in files:`, then your code would work as is. Currently `filename` is a `list` and `os.path.basename()` takes a `str`.

Comment: now , my script says ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long 
 IV = infile.read(16)

Comment: Ask a separate question. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), narrow down the problem and provide a minimal code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect to get the file size using this: `filesize = infile.read(16)`?